# How do I soft wrap my Text widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text

I have tried all that I know to get the text to softwrap. I have looked at other people's codes and solutions. Nothing seems to work. Is there something I am missing?

[image: Flutter Text softwrap not working]

I have tried wrapping it in an `Expanded()` and a `Row()` widget, but these only make the whole text disappear. I have tried `Containers()` with varying sizes, `Padding()` `Wrap()`. I just need help, please.

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPostTapped,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          userProfilePicture == null
              ? Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/UserImage.png',
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )
              : Image.network(userProfilePicture!),
          const SizedBox(width: 8),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'New follower',
                        style: LabelText.normal(
                            size: 14,
                            color: AppColors.dark1,
                            height: 1.2,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Container(
                        height: 8,
                        width: 8,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                            color: AppColors.info),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    time != null ? time.toString() : '08:23',
                    style: LabelText.Small(
                        size: 12,
                        color: AppColors.dark2,
                        height: 0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        letterSpacing: 0.06),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
// This widget does not soft wrap.
              Text(
                userName == null
                    ? 'Shola Aremu just started following you. Say hi!'
                    : '$userName just started following you. Say hi!',
                softWrap: true,
                style: TextStyles.bodySmall(
                    color: AppColors.dark1,
                    size: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    height: 0),
              ),
// This widget above does not softwrap.
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

This bit of code above is called here. Where `NewFollowerNotification()` is the name of the class being called.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 25, right: 25),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Notifications',
                      style: TextStyles.heading5(
                          color: AppColors.dark2,
                          size: 20,
                          height: 0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                        color: AppColors.info),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                      child: Text(
                        '8',
                        style: LabelText.extraSmall(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 10,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            letterSpacing: 0.05,
                            height: 0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                'Clear all',
                style: TextStyles.bodySmall(
                    color: AppColors.mainColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    size: 14,
                    height: 0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, bottom: 16),
            child: Text(
              'Today',
              style: TextStyles.heading6(
                  size: 16,
                  height: 0,
                  color: AppColors.dark2,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
// The class is called here
          NewFollowerNotification(),
// The class is called here
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I want the Text widget to softwrap. It overflows instead. I expect the part beyond the screen to come down beneath the rendered text (softwrap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting vertical overflow, wrap the Column with Expanded to give maximum available width.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: onPostTapped,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        userProfilePicture == null
            ? Image.asset(
                'assets/images/UserImage.png',
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
            : Image.network(userProfilePicture!),
        const SizedBox(width: 8),
        Expanded(   // wrap this Column with Expanded
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'New follower',
                        style: LabelText.normal(
                            size: 14,
                            color: AppColors.dark1,
                            height: 1.2,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Container(
                        height: 8,
                        width: 8,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                            color: AppColors.info),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    time != null ? time.toString() : '08:23',
                    style: LabelText.Small(
                        size: 12,
                        color: AppColors.dark2,
                        height: 0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        letterSpacing: 0.06),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        // This widget does not soft wrap.
              Text(
                userName == null
                    ? 'Shola Aremu just started following you. Say hi!'
                    : '$userName just started following you. Say hi!',
                softWrap: true,
                style: TextStyles.bodySmall(
                    color: AppColors.dark1,
                    size: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    height: 0),
              ),
        // This widget above does not softwrap.
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. But why? What is the reason? I have a text widget in another custom widget that softwraps itself automatically. I guess code just does it things sometimes. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @NicholasEkubi You have to focus on size of the parent widget. If the parent of Text widget has fixed width or scrollable, it can be displayed without overflow. But since Column does not have indication of width nor scrollable, it does not softwrap itself.